# Do laravel View::make passes controller variables to view?

Tags: php, view, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

Lets say I have simple page which loads articles through controller to blade template -> articles.blade.php. In this template I want add extra section which loads all categories from Category controller. I've tried to add this page with `<?php echo View::make('category'); ?>` command. But my guess it's loading directly VIEW file, without touching controller, so variables from controller is not passed to view. And error I get is this:

`Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception`

I'd like to know if I'm right about this ? If no, how I should add view to template, so it would load category info.

Comment: I suggest you revisit the Views section in http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should pass the `categories` from the same (Probably `ArticleController`) controller, using something like this:

```
// Probably ArticleController for articles
$articles = Article::all();
$categories = Category::all();
return View::make('articles')
           ->with('articles', $articles)
           ->with('categories', $categories);
```

If you are passing the articles from `ArticleController` then also load and pass the categories from that controller.

Comment: Thank for answer. This example is working, hovewer I want to update only categories section on ajax call, instead of whole page.